# How to pass multiple arguments that came from different tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments

This is a follow-up to that question I posted last time which was on how can I give access of tkinter widgets to modules that I imported. I ended up solving that problem using `command=lambda: module_name.function(widget)`.

**main.py**

```
from tkinter import *

import checkbox_operation
import receipt_operation


class cafemanagementsystem:

    def __init__(self, cms):
        self.cms = cms
        cms.title("Cafe Management System")

    self.b1var = IntVar(value=1)
    self.b2var = IntVar(value=1)
    self.b1v = StringVar()
    self.b2v = StringVar()
    self.b1v.set("0")
    self.b2v.set("0")

    self.b1 = Checkbutton(self.bevmenu, command=lambda: checkbox_operation.check(self.b1var, self.b1v, self.b1a, self.b2var, self.b2v, self.b2a), text="Latte", variable=self.b1var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(
        row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    self.b1a = Entry(self.bevmenu, bd=2, textvariable=self.b1v)
    self.b1a.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

    self.b2 = Checkbutton(self.bevmenu, command=lambda: checkbox_operation.check(self.b1var, 
    self.b1v, self.b1a, self.b2var, self.b2v, self.b2a), text="Espresso", variable=self.b2var).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
    self.b2a = Entry(self.bevmenu, bd=2, textvariable=self.b2v)
    self.b2a.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
```

**checkbox_operation**

```
from tkinter import NORMAL, DISABLED


def check(b1var, b1v, b1a, b2var, b2v, b2a):
    if b1var.get() == 1:
        b1a.config(state=NORMAL)
    elif b1var.get() == 0:
        b1a.config(state=DISABLED)
        b1v.set("0")
    if b2var.get() == 1:
        b2a.config(state=NORMAL)
    elif b2var.get() == 0:
        b2a.config(state=DISABLED)
        b2v.set("0")
```

My problem is that `b1` and `b2` are 2 of 16 checkboxes that will pass 3 arguments each to `checkbox_operation.check`. If I do it to all of them as shown in my `main.py`, it would mean that I have to pass 48 different arguments in each checkbox and make `main.py` become very unreadable.

How can I make so that `b1` only passes `self.b1var, self.b1v, self.b1a`, `b2` `self.b2var, self.b2v, self.b2a` and so on to `checkbox_operation.check`?

Comment: Have you tried using `<any tkinter widget>.config(command=...)` after creating all of your widgets?

Comment: Normally SO isnt the right platform for your question. Here we debug your code and dont do a review on it.